# Populating SeriesCollection with Range from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I'm planning a userform, that will generate graphs using data from other files. I was trying to populate `seriescollection` from Chart1 using data from another workbook. Although, my program causes empty `seriescollection`. Below is code for this program (some of the parts were cut out, because they're not relevant to the problem).

```
Dim ChtsBig(), openWb As Workbook, genWb As Workbook
Set genWb = ActiveWorkbook
If ListBox1.ListCount = 0 Then MsgBox ("Select files!")
ReDim Preserve ChtsBig(1 To ListBox1.ListCount)
For i = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount
    fileWb = ListBox1.List(i - 1, 1)
    Set openWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fileWb, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set sht1 = openWb.Worksheets(1)
    Set sht2 = openWb.Worksheets("Cycles")
    Set ChtsBig(i) = genWb.Charts.Add
    With ChtsBig(i)
        .Name = "Cell " & Left(ListBox1.List(i - 1, 0), 4)
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        j = 1
        k = 1
        For curr_cyc = TextBox7.Value To TextBox8.Value Step TextBox9.Value
            Do
                If sht2.Cells(1 + j, 1) = curr_cyc Then
                    cyc_row = 1 + j
                    found = True
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop Until found = True Or sht2.Cells(2 + j, 1) = Empty
            If found = True Then
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(k).Name = "Cycle " & curr_cyc & " Charge"
                .SeriesCollection(k).XValues = sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 4), 16), sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 5), 16))
                .SeriesCollection(k).Values = sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 4), 9), sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 5), 9))
                Numpoint1 = .SeriesCollection(k).Points.Count
                .SeriesCollection(k).Points(Numpoint1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleTriangle
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(k + 1).Name = "Cycle " & curr_cyc + 1 & " Discharge"
                .SeriesCollection(k + 1).XValues = sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 6), 16), sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 7), 16))
                .SeriesCollection(k + 1).Values = sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 6), 9), sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 7), 9))
                .SeriesCollection(k + 1).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
                .SeriesCollection(k + 1).Border.LineStyle = xlDash
                Numpoint2 = .SeriesCollection(k + 1).Points.Count
                .SeriesCollection(k + 1).Points(Numpoint2).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleDiamond
                currentSeriesColorindex = (k + 1) / 2 + 40
                If (k + 1) / 2 + 40 < 57 Then
                    currentSeriesColorindex = (k + 1) / 2 + 40
                Else
                    currentSeriesColorindex = (k + 1) / 2 + 32
                End If
                .SeriesCollection(k).Points(Numpoint1).MarkerForegroundColorIndex = currentSeriesColorindex
                .SeriesCollection(k).Points(Numpoint1).MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = currentSeriesColorindex
                .SeriesCollection(k + 1).Points(Numpoint2).MarkerForegroundColorIndex = currentSeriesColorindex
                .SeriesCollection(k + 1).Points(Numpoint2).MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = currentSeriesColorindex
                .SeriesCollection(k + 1).Border.ColorIndex = currentSeriesColorindex
                .SeriesCollection(k).Border.ColorIndex = currentSeriesColorindex
            End If
            found = False
            k = k + 2
        Next
        .HasTitle = False
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 2.5
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = 4.5
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 0.0001
        .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#0,0"
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Caption = "Charge / Ah"
        .Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Caption = "Voltage / V"
        .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = False
        .Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = False
        .Legend.IncludeInLayout = False
        .Legend.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).MajorGridlines.Border.Color = RGB(160, 160, 160)
        .Axes(xlCategory).MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDash
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.Color = RGB(160, 160, 160)
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDash
    End With
    openWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next
```

While debugging this range: `sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 4), 16), sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 5), 16))` has correct values in Value2, although `.SeriesCollection(k).XValues` is empty.

Once clarification sht1 has raw data for chart, but divided into chunks (for example one data set is between row 250 to 500). Sht2 contain information about position of those chunks.

If it helps, here is how graph should look like:[Generated Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNDn7.png)

Answer (score 0):

This pattern:

```vb
If found = True Then
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(k).Name = "Cycle " & curr_cyc & " Charge"
```

is prone to some issues since it depends on whether there are pre-existing series.  Since `NewSeries` returns the added series, this would be more robust:

```vb
Dim s1 As Series

If found = True Then
    Set s1 = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries() 'get a reference on creation
    s1.Name = "Cycle " & curr_cyc & " Charge"
```

It's also a good idea whenever adding a new chart to make sure excel hasn't "auto-added" any series for you, by checking the `SeriesCollection.Count` before you start adding your series.

Comment: Hi, thank for bringing this up. I usually add `ChartArea.Clear` after creating new chart.
Do you have any idea why my `SeriesCollection(k)` is empty after doing this :
`.SeriesCollection(k).XValues = sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 4), 16), sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 5), 16))`
`.SeriesCollection(k).Values = sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 4), 9), sht1.Cells(3 + sht2.Cells(cyc_row, 5), 9))`

Comment: I could only guess there's no data in that range, because either the sheets or input ranges are not what you expect.

Comment: I have checked, and even if i assign sht1 to Worksheet in Another workbook, the above expression references to range in Workbook where macro was launched, no the open one with data.
It does however properly reads values from sht2.

Comment: It's difficult to see how that could happen - the assignment of sht1 seems fine. The only thing I could see which might be an issue is if the file you assign to openWb is already open, in which case Excel has a tendency to assign some other open file in place of the one you expect. If you're still having problems and can share your workbooks I can take a look - either share via box/dropbox/etc